# Centering a panel in GWT using the layoutpanel system

Tags: gwt, layout, layoutpanels

On the GWT developer site there is an example showing a panel that is in the middle of a page.  Is this possible to have a fixed with panel in the middle of a page using the GWT layoutpanels?

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels

Answer (score 3):

There's a good old CSS trick for centering *fixed-size*, *absolute* boxes, using automatic CSS layouting (no JavaScript required):

- First center the top left corner of the box by using `top: 50%; left: 50%;`
  Of course, the box will be too far to the bottom/right now.
- Then subtract half of the box's height/width by using margins. (It's fixed-size, so you can calculate "half of the height/width" with pen and paper :-)

Example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
        height: 300px;       width: 400px;  /* Using "px" here, but you */
                                            /* can also use "em" etc.   */
        top: 50%;            left: 50%;
        margin-top: -150px;  margin-left: -200px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="box">Box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apply this style to your LayoutPanel - I don't have a full code example for that, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: The LayoutPanel provides an onResize() event for child panels that implement the NeedsResize interface.  You can use this hook if the various panel sizes are subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect with simple css.  For example:

```
<html><head>
<style>
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer"><div class="inner" /></div>
</body></html>
```

Once the basic effect is created in plain CSS using absolutely-positioned objects, you can recreate it with the LayoutPanels, since they're essentially a CSS constraint system.

Comment: This doesn't create a fixed-width inner div~

Comment: Good solution for *fixed-percentage* boxes, though. The solution for *fixed-size* is a bit different, but it's still possible with simple css!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make a fixed-width layer center itself automatically in a LayoutPanel.  However, you can insert the layer into the DOM to get its size, and then calculate the proper offsets yourself.  You can see how Google does this (not in a LayoutPanel) in  the code for DialogBox.center();